# Will Django run on Windows Server 2019 or 2016?

Tags: django, windows, flutter, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

I am trying to launch my app which i have created using flutter and django.I have started a server, the server provider is asking which OS i want in my server ,he is giving the option of Windows server 2016 and 2019. Which one should i choose?
How will Django work in a Windows Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: https://medium.com/@ayushi21095/steps-to-deploy-python-django-web-application-on-windows-iis-server-379b2b87fcf9

The Windows Server 2019 is a leap over the 2016 version when it comes to security. While the 2016 version was based on the use of shielded VMs, the 2019 version offers extra support to run Linux VMs. In addition, the 2019 version is based on the protect, detect and respond approach to security. VMConnect offers additional support to troubleshoot common networking issues.

Another useful addition is the Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection (WDATP) feature that amplifies the preventive aspect of the system’s security application.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I just wanted to know that will Django work on windows server. Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: The linked-to article relies on using FastCGI, but per this article, the wfastcgi project is no longer being maintained:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2022